# If statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Alright so this should be a relatively easy one. When I run the program I notice that the Damage integer is not passing down to the Damage_Applied if statement. It will work properly before the Damage_Applied integer though. How can I carry the Damage integer down to the second if statement or should I rewrite this whole part?

```
elif menu_option == 2: 
    print "Damage Taken?"
    Damage = int(raw_input(prompt))
    print "Where would you like damage to be applied?"
    print "1. HP"
    print "2. CP"
    print "3. Armor"

    Damage_Applied = int(raw_input(prompt))

    if Damage_Applied == 1:
        HP = HP - Damage
    elif Damage_Applied == 2:
        CP = CP - Damage
    elif Damage_Applied == 3:
        Armor = Armor - Damage
```

Comment: At your inner `if` statement you are still inside of your `elif` statement, `Damage` should have a value.

Comment: Works for me (with minor mods to allow for the rest of the program that's not included).

Comment: Are you getting an error saying that Damage cannot be resolved or are you just noticing wrong behavior of your program?

Comment: Some syntactic sugar: `HP -= Damage` == `HP = HP - Damage`

Comment: I am not getting an error, just noticing that it is not actually deducting from the variable.

Comment: Well I changed it from HP = HP - Damage to HP -= Damage and it appears to be working now! Thank you.

Comment: It make no sense, they are different syntaxs for the same operation.

Comment: could it be that you tested this code with `Damage_Applied not in (1, 2, 3)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define:-

- HP
- CP
- Armor

In Python, to subtract a value from another value, you need to have both of the values. Currently, in your code, HP = None, which isn't a numeric value, so HP needs to be defined as a numeric value (the same applies to CP and Armor), so we will define this as 100, like so:-

```
HP = 100
```

And, we will also need to do this with CP and Armor, so, like this:-

```
CP = 100
Armor = 100
```

You can obviously change the 100s to anything you like, and it will still work.

The full code would look something like this:-

### Python 3.x

```
elif menu_option == 2:
    HP= 100 #Defining 'HP'
    CP = 100 #Defining 'CP'
    Armor = 100 #Defining 'Armor'
    #For future reference, make sure ALL variables used in an 
    #if statement are defined before using them

    print("Damage Taken?")
    Damage = int(input(prompt))
    print("Where would you like damage to be applied?")
    print("1. HP")
    print("2. CP")
    print("3. Armor")

    Damage_Applied = int(input(prompt))

    if Damage_Applied == 1:
        HP = HP - Damage
    elif Damage_Applied == 2:
        CP = CP - Damage
    elif Damage_Applied == 3:
        Armor = Armor - Damage
```

### Python 2.x

```
elif menu_option == 2:
    HP= 100 #Defining 'HP'
    CP = 100 #Defining 'CP'
    Armor = 100 #Defining 'Armor'
    #For future reference, make sure ALL variables used in an 
    #if statement are defined before using them

    print "Damage Taken?"
    Damage = int(raw_input(prompt))
    print "Where would you like damage to be applied?"
    print "1. HP"
    print "2. CP"
    print "3. Armor"

    Damage_Applied = int(raw_input(prompt))

    if Damage_Applied == 1:
        HP = HP - Damage
    elif Damage_Applied == 2:
        CP = CP - Damage
    elif Damage_Applied == 3:
        Armor = Armor - Damage
```

That code should work. If you need any help, contact me directly at 'aaron@dibdibguy.com'

Enjoy your new code!